# Error al instalar Carbon en laravel

Tags: laravel, carbon

Estoy intentando instalar carbon en laravel pero me da el siguiente error

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - laravel/framework v5.7.24 requires nesbot/carbon ^1.26.3 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.26.3, 1.26.4, 1.27.0, 1.28.0, 1.29.0, 1.29.1, 1.29.2, 1.30.0, 1.31.0, 1.31.1, 1.32.0, 1.33.0, 1.34.0, 1.34.1, 1.34.2, 1.34.3, 1.34.4, 1.35.0, 1.35.1, 1.36.0, 1.36.1, 1.36.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - laravel/framework v5.7.24 requires nesbot/carbon ^1.26.3 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.26.3, 1.26.4, 1.27.0, 1.28.0, 1.29.0, 1.29.1, 1.29.2, 1.30.0, 1.31.0, 1.31.1, 1.32.0, 1.33.0, 1.34.0, 1.34.1, 1.34.2, 1.34.3, 1.34.4, 1.35.0, 1.35.1, 1.36.0, 1.36.1, 1.36.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - laravel/framework v5.7.24 requires nesbot/carbon ^1.26.3 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.26.3, 1.26.4, 1.27.0, 1.28.0, 1.29.0, 1.29.1, 1.29.2, 1.30.0, 1.31.0, 1.31.1, 1.32.0, 1.33.0, 1.34.0, 1.34.1, 1.34.2, 1.34.3, 1.34.4, 1.35.0, 1.35.1, 1.36.0, 1.36.1, 1.36.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.7.24, required as 5.7.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.24].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Por lo que veo la versión no es compatible pero es esto posible que  puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Laravel 5.7 no es compatible con Carbon 2.x**, por lo cual no es posible que instales dicha versión si vas a utilizar Laravel 5.7, a partir de Laravel 5.8 se podrá alternar entre las versiones 1.x o 2.x de Carbon.

Si deseas ver más información sobre el desarrollo de dicha funcionalidad en Laravel y su estado, revisa el siguiente enlace: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/25320

Comment: Ya se puede actualizar a laravel 5.8 ? No veo la documentación pero si este enlace https://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade

Comment: Aún no se puede, al menos no a una versión estable.